# How to compare two strings that represent numbers in c#?

Tags: c#, string, numbers, compare

I have two strings **"73248723847239847283974283749238"** and **"98231912938129381290120378988945"** They contain numbers and may be 50 chracters long.  I found just one solution: convert it to array of numbers and compare sums of it but it is not very good from performance side.  Does anybody know how i can compare it?

Comment: Why can't you just compare them as regular strings?

Comment: Because this strings represents numbers and I have to compare it and find biggest one of it.

Comment: How does converting them to an array of numbers and comparing the sums get you the right answer? I mean, 500 = 5, while 199 = 19. 500 is clearly larger than 199, but 5 is less than 19.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about zeros within, so thank you.

Comment: Even without zeros that wouldn't work.  `12 => 1 + 2`  wheres `21 => 2 + 1` and `2 + 1 == 1 + 2`.

Comment: Have you considered BigIntegers? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have to compare it and find biggest one of it.

You could handle it with [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.Parse("73248723847239847283974283749238");
BigInteger b2 = BigInteger.Parse("98231912938129381290120378988945");

BigInteger result = BigInteger.Max(b1, b2);
```

---

> convert it to array of numbers and compare sums of it but it is not very good from performance side

Side note - performance is the smallest problem of this approach

Comment: A class String contains CompareTo method, it's working good in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Make it the same length with PadLeft() and then comapre it:

```
var s1 = "73248723847239847283974283749238";
var s2 = "98231912938129381290120378988945";

s1 = s1.PadLeft(50, '0');
s2 = s2.PadLeft(50, '0');

var compareResult = s1.CompareTo(s2);
```